# String Tokenizer/Regex to find email address/IP Address in a file

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I have a document with lines containing email addresses and IP addresses. I need to split the document in terms of email addresses and IP addresses to store each IP/email address or words in the file in an array.

Is there a way to use regex/String Tokenizer to find email/IP address to do this? I am aware of how regex/String Tokenizer can be used to separate words in a sentence line by line. Just not sure how to find email/IP addresses. 
Because the file may contain illegal characters like @ \ // which should not be included in the array.

**For example my document contains:**

You can contact test@test.com, the address is 192.168.1.1.

**My array should contain:**

You

can

contact

test@test.com

the

address

is

192.168.1.1

Comment: Are you looking to tokenize the string and then run the regex against each token to find the subsequent matches?

I think this is close to what you need: http://regexr.com/3gspa, creating a regex that will match all based on the RFC but I think this should work

Comment: Yes, I'd like to tokenize the string. I had a problem because I couldn't use String Tokenizer to retrieve the tokens as the IP address and email address would be split into separate tokens because of the symbols they include.
 Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex for email address is:

```
[\w!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[\w!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[\w](?:[\w-]*[\w])?\.)+[\w](?:[\w-]*[\w])?
```

And the regex for IP address is:

```
((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|((1\d{2})|([1-9]?\d)))\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|((1\d{2})|([1-9]?\d))))
```

In my opinion, you can use `java.util.regex.Matcher` and call method `matcher.group(0)` like:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<your regex here>");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
 List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
 while (m.find())
     strs.add(m.group(0));
```

These may works fine, but I'm not test yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [regexr](https://regexr.com/3gspj) with some examples and a regex that should work for you.

Regex is (the email portion is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/1843183), I'm also not positive it copied and pasted correct.):

```
(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Comment: This helps. Thanks!